# Sound issues on Win 11 (?)

Tags: sound

I have an "animation" which uses `Manipulate`(manipulates time) and I want to play sound at the specific times. On my PC (Win10) it works smoothly and without any problems, but on the PC with Win11 there's a significant problem with sound, many times it just doesn't work, and there are big lags when it should play.

I need something comparable to beep sound (block collisions) and I've tried doing it with e.g.:

```mathematica
EmitSound[AudioGenerator[{"Sin", 350}, 0.02]]
```

or

```mathematica
EmitSound[Sound[SampledSoundFunction[Sin[0.125 #] &, 400, 15000]]
```

The animation itself shouldn't be a problem - it works good on both Win10 and 11 without adding sound. It propably isn't the issue of a performance as well; on both machines I have comparable benchmark results.

The first one (using `Audiogenerator`) needs to be extended to at least 0.05s on Win 11 - otherwise it just plays nothing, while it works even with 0.02s on Win 10. I've tried with playing sound by previously importing it from a file as well and the problem is the same.

I've tried that on two different Win10 and two different Win11 (with different CPU's etc.) computers and issue occurs **only** on Win11.
With that it looks that it might be some issue with OS or maybe audio codecs.

Maybe anyone here had a similar problem before?

Comment: "there are big lags when it should play." There are such issues with HDMI/DP connected displays' speakers.

Comment: Hm, this doesn't look like the case here. I don't have speakers in display. Also, I've tried that on notebook (Win 11) and problem is the same; even with completely disabled audio output via HDMI.